# c++ - Can't access gSOAP web services with HTTPS

Tags: c++, ssl, soap, https, gsoap

I'm trying to hit a web service which I built with SSL on gSOAP 2.8.4. But it doesn't works. Relevant information:

- Everything works fine using HTTP. The problem only happens when I use HTTPS.
- Message error:

> Error -1 fault: SOAP-ENV:Client [no subcode]
>   "End of file or no input: Operation interrupted or timed out (60 s receive delay) (60 s send delay)"
>   Detail: [no detail]

The problem doesn't seem to be a low timeout because the error is instantaneous.

Server context:

```
if (soap_ssl_server_context(&soap,
    SOAP_SSL_DEFAULT,   /* use SOAP_SSL_REQUIRE_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION to verify clients: client must provide a key file e.g. "client.pem" and "password" */
    "server.pem",   /* keyfile (cert+key): see SSL docs to create this file */
    password,       /* password to read the private key in the key file */
    "cacert.pem",   /* cacert file to store trusted certificates (to authenticate clients) */
    "./",       /* capath */
    NULL,   /* DH file name or DH param key len bits (e.g. "1024"), if NULL use RSA 2048 bits (SOAP_SSL_RSA_BITS) */
    NULL,       /* if randfile!=NULL: use a file with random data to seed randomness */
    "server"        /* server identification for SSL session cache (unique server name, e.g. use argv[0]) */
    ))
{
```

Client context:

```
if (soap_ssl_client_context(&soap,
    SOAP_SSL_DEFAULT,   /* use SOAP_SSL_DEFAULT in production code */
    NULL,       /* keyfile (cert+key): required only when client must authenticate to server (see SSL docs to create this file) */
    NULL,       /* password to read the keyfile */
    "cacert.pem",   /* optional cacert file to store trusted certificates, use cacerts.pem for all public certificates issued by common CAs */
    "./",       /* optional capath to directory with trusted certificates */
    NULL        /* if randfile!=NULL: use a file with random data to seed randomness */
    ))
{
```

All the certificates and passwords are correct.
What could be the problem?

---

Edit:
I compiled the code with -DDEBUG. This appears in TEST.log

> Free ID hashtable
>   Read 0 bytes from socket=4/fd=0
>   Sending back fault struct for error code -1
>   soap_instantiate_SOAP_ENV__Fault(-1, , )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved this problem. The server certificate was wrong. The Common Name in this application should be equal to the host name.